# Open Source alternative for Confluent MySQL Sink Connector?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Are there any alternative options to Confluent's MySQL sink connector?

Comment: Do you mean JDBC Sink Connector?

Answer (score 1):

The Confluent JDBC sink connector *is* open source and usage falls under the Confluent Community License, which includes clause such as free to use without offering as a hosted software

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking to do with the MySQL sink connector? I'm part of a team working on an alternative option to Kafka Connect so this might fit what you're looking for.

Check out: GitHub - ConduitIO/conduit: Data Integration for Production Data Stores.

Conduit is meant to be a bit more general-purpose than connect. Conduit has the capability of being a drop-in replacement for Connect and we're working hard to make that even easier. We're still very much in the early stages of this project and we're trying to build more and more connectors. Our philosophy around connectors is to be real-time first, double down on change data capture capabilities, and have permissive licensing. If you need something that isn't there, I'd recommend jumping into the [github](https://github.com/ConduitIO/conduit) discussions on the repo, the team is pretty responsive. or join our [discord](https://discord.com/invite/pN24QPca6b) to speak directly to the team for questions or feedback!

Comment: Could you provide an example with mysql? Since it's not in the docs https://github.com/ConduitIO/conduit/blob/main/docs/connectors.md